# Is there any way to differentiate @here from @<mynick> in Slack?

Tags: slack

I'm having a problem managing notification on Slack. Generally `@here` is to blame for this. I usually don't care about those anyway.

Is there a way to get some form of separation between people who `@here`, or `@group` vs people who explicitly tag me.

Comment: Please add more details and context. Have you already read [Use mentions in Slack](https://slack.com/help/articles/205240127-Use-mentions-in-Slack)?

Answer (score 1):

One way to manage this is to mute such notifications in channels where this is misused. You can do this in the channel notification settings, which you can access on desktop by right-clicking the channel name and choosing ‘Change notifications’. There is an option to include `@channel` and `@here` which you can untick.

This means that uses of those mechanisms in those channels won’t be promoted to you in the same way that mentions are.

If it is helpful, there are instructions here: https://medium.com/@Paul__Walsh/how-to-mute-channel-and-here-commands-inside-our-slack-dbb4a0177e06#16c2

Comment: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/289691)

Comment: Thanks for the comment—having checked your link, can I check that you are drawing attention to the fact that I haven't provided the actual info in the answer, and not something related to the actual link? I regularly provide that link (which isn’t my own) to people with this issue since the Slack docs don’t focus on this. I would be happy to edit my post to provide more info if that is the case.

Comment: I didn’t hear back, so I added some more info to the solution I had already given.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for updating your post. The goal of [webapps.se] is for answers to be as self contained as possible, to avoid link rot. The edit does that, though it doesn't necessarily answer the question (but I'm not judging that)

Comment: You’re welcome! Happy to follow the best practice. And thanks—your response was 10x clearer than a link to a page which suggests not using links! 
As for answering the question, I don’t think there is a better answer sadly, but I do think that muting problematic notifications goes a long way to helping you action explit tagging (direct mentions).